# Current BotMan and DIalogFlow integration?

Tags: php, dialogflow-es, chatbot, botman

I want to know how it is the current way to integrate BotMan and DialogFlow.
I use BotMan with pure php and the web driver.
Please help to correctly integrate with example if possible please, but at least a guide. Its for school project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the dialogflow api and integrate the botman with the dialogflow, follow these steps given in the link below, it works for me.

[Integrate Botman with Dialogflow](https://github.com/genkovich/DialogFlowBotManMiddleware)

However, there's still problem like the botman cannot go to the right intent, and it only go to the default welcome and default fallback intent only. To solve that problem I add 'input.unknown' to the others intent and write the code in botman like below:

```
$dialogflow = DialogFlow::create('en');
$botman->middleware->received($dialogflow);
$botman->hears('(input.*)', function ($bot) {
 $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();
 $bot->reply($extras['apiReply']);
})->middleware($dialogflow);
```

for more discussion regarding the topic you can view it on the link given below.

[Adding input to hears and dialogflow intent](https://github.com/botman/botman/issues/873)